# Unknown attribute when creating association object between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have three models: `User`, `Event` who have a `has_many through`-Association via `Attendance`. When creating a relationship between a user and event in the `rails console --sandbox` like `user1.attended_events.build(event_id: event1.id)` I get an `unknown attribute 'event_id' for Event` also the other way around when writing `event1.attendees.build(attendee_id: user1.id)`: `unknown attribute 'attendee_id' for User`.

For `Attendance` I created a table like this:

```
class CreateAttendances < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :attendances do |t|
      t.references :event, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :attendee_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :attendances, :attendee_id
    add_index :attendances, [:event_id, :attendee_id], unique: true
 end
end
```

This is how my models look like (Users can also create Events):

User-Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :events, inverse_of: "creator", foreign_key: "creator_id" , dependent: :destroy

   has_many :attendances, class_name: "Attendance", inverse_of: "attendee", foreign_key: "attendee_id", dependent: :destroy
   has_many :attended_events, through: :attendances, source: :event
end
```

Event-Model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "creator_id"

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :attendees, through: :attendances
end
```

Attendance-Model:

```
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :attendances
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :attendances
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `event1.attendees.build(some_params)` you are trying to build a new user, and yes, the User model has no `attendee_id` attribute.

It should be `event1.attendances.build(attendee_id: user1.id)`. The same is for `user1.attendances.build(event_id: event1.id)`.

UPDATE.

Not sure if I understood you question in the comment correctly, but I'll try to answer.

Let imagine that we have a `user`, `event1` and `event2` instances, and `user.attended_events == [event1, event2]`. The `user` doesn't want to participate anymore in the `event2`, so you need to destroy this association.

```
User.attendances.find_by(event_id: event2.id).destroy
```

It will destroy only Attendance instance, and it becomes `user.attended_events == [event1]`. And in the `event2.attendees` array will no longer be the `user`

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification! What I'd like to do in the end is having access to the Event's attendees. Is there a way of having the attendees in `event1.attendees` both in its array and the attendance table, so e.g. if a user doesn't want to participate anymore by destroying their attendance entry, the event's array will update itself? I'm quite unsure when rails does its magic and when not.